# return random 5 records from last 20 records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Simply I have the following

table with records , i want to return randomly 5 records from the last 20 record (order by id desc)

so how we can do it fast
thanks for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select * from
(
  select * from your_table 
  order by id desc limit 20
) as lastest_results
order by rand()
limit 5;
```

Comment: additional to it, if you have make `id` as primary key, the performance won't be that bad

Answer (score 2):

Use an inner query to return the last 20, and an outer query to select 5 of them randomly.  This may be slow though.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20) t ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slow method but it gets the JOB done:

```
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5;
```

If you are using a large table this can become very slow, 
There are multiple alternative that you can read about here

[Alternative to order by rand](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/msyql-alternative-order-by-rand/)

Comment: You cannot order by id, desc, and RAND() without using a subquery like the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

If you have a time parameter to sort them by for example the last 20 records then use this.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY insert_time DESC, RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

OR

**SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC, RAND() LIMIT 5;**